# Use native function pointer for listening to managed event / marshaling issue

Tags: c++-cli, function-pointers, marshalling

I'm writing a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly bridge in order to be able to call into my .NET class library from old C++ application.

In one of my classes in the .NET library one can attach to an event whenever some message needs to be displayed (to console or whatever depending on calling application).

```
class NetApi
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReported;
}
```

To call this from native C++ application, I defined the following pointer/delegate bridge:

```
typedef void(*MessageHandler)(const char* msg);
delegate void ManagedMessageHandler([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)] String^ msg);
```

Omitting from glue for connecting everything (attaching to `MessageReported`, removing `sender` from `EventHandler`, etc...),  here is how I create managed delegate from native function pointer:

```
class NetApiBridge
{
    public:
      void SetMessageHandler(MessageHandler handler)
      {
          wrappedListener = (ManagedMessageHandler^)Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((IntPtr)handler, ManagedMessageHandler::typeid);        
      }          

    private:
        msclr::auto_gcroot<NetApi^ > wrappedApi;
        msclr::auto_gcroot<ManagedMessageHandler^ > wrappedListener;

        // In another helper ref class in fact, but here pseudo code to simplify
        void onMessageReported(Object^ sender, MessageEventArgs^ e)
        {
            if (!wrappedListener) { return; }

            wrappedListenter(e->Message); // Send message to native function pointer
        }
}
```

And I'm almost there when creating dummy C++ test code:

```
void messageHandler(const char* s)
{
    cout << s; 
}
void main()
{
   NetApiBridge api = new NetApiBridge();
   api->SetMessageHandler(&messageHandler);

   api->Measure();
   delete api;
}
```

Everything goes fine, events are reported correctly except .... except I receive a `PInvokeStackImbalance` from Managed Debugging Assistant when leaving the native handler and I clearly don't know why ?

What's wrong with marshaling `const char*` as `UnmanagedType::LPStr` here with `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` ?

NB: C++ bridge is compiled in x86 if it is important to know here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef void(*MessageHandler)(const char* msg);
delegate void ManagedMessageHandler([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)] String^ msg);
```

Your delegate declaration is not compatible with the function pointer declaration in 32-bit code.  The default calling convention in native code is almost always `__cdecl`.  The default for delegates is `__stdcall`.  A somewhat quirky choice but inspired because interop was assumed to be useful to make OS calls, Windows and COM use __stdcall.

The mismatch right now causes the delegate stub to pop the arguments off the stack.  So does the native code so the stack gets imbalanced by 4 bytes.  The MDA is there to help you diagnose this common mishap.

You'll have to help and get them to agree.  Either with the delegate declaration:

```
   using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
   ...
   [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
   delegate void ManagedMessageHandler(String^ msg);
```

Or the function pointer declaration:

```
   typedef void (__stdcall * MessageHandler)(const char* msg);
```

Comment: You're my hero for today ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'll return the compliment, best question I've read all week.  Very well done, you made it very easy to help you.